# How to marshall Element to JAXB Axis2 response object

Tags: java, jaxb, apache-axis, saml

I am using Axis2 wsdl2java with JAXB data bindings to create the response object for a web service that returns a SAML assertion. The response object is generated with data types specific to the SAML assertion schema as you would expect. However, the system and SDK I am integrating with that generates the assertion returns it as an org.w3c.dom.Element.

(So the flow is service consumer -> my web service -> SAML identity provider -(returns assertion as Element)-> returns assertion to consumer)

My question is how I can marshall the assertion from an Element to the Axis2 response object without having to manually map every element and attribute? While I'm sure that can be made to work, it seems fragile and prone to error.

Comment: Relevant: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152046/unmarshalling-xml-using-jaxb 2) http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/file-input-output-tutorials/4062-how-parse-object-xml-using-jaxb.html 3) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html#unmars

Comment: Also note that XML -> POJO is "unmarshaling", POJO -> XML is "marshaling".

Comment: Thanks Brian - my question was confusing, what I really want to happen is to get the Axis2 response object marshalled to the SOAP response message.

Answer (score 1):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations are configuration by exception, this means that you only need to add annotations where you need the XML representation to differ from the default based on the Java class.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

JAXB offers APIs to `unmarshal` (XML to object) from many different sources.  You can use one of the following methods to unmarshal from  a DOM node on [`javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html).

- [`unmarshal(org.w3c.dom.Node)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29)
- [`unmarshal(javax.xml.transform.Source, Class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20java.lang.Class%29) and give it an instance of [`javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMSource.html)

Comment: Thanks Blaise - I'll need to spend some time trying this out. It seems like I have two options - one is to change the response object so that Axis2 can marshall it using the automatically generated MessageInOutReceiver class, or I need to change the marshalling code in the MessageInOutReceiver...

Comment: Thanks Blaise. As I look at your links and re-read my question, I may have asked the wrong question. Basically I am trying to use the Axis2 generated response objects in a way that allows me to marshall the SAML assertion into the SOAP response. I thought that using the native Element data type would be the best way to do this, but perhaps there is someway to use a string that would be better? Or should I use Element and