# Java : Read multiple xml from a single text file and store them as a List<string>

Tags: java, xml, file-io, xml-parsing, java-7

Consider the following text file with content :

```
<TESTFILE>
            <TESTFILE_ID>654316</TESTFILE_ID>
            <TESTVIN>ERE</TESTVIN>
            <TESTTYPE_ER>FD 91 MUX</TESTTYPE_ER>
        <TEST_RT>
                <TEST41_LONG_CS>B001_001_001</TEST41_LONG_CS>
        </TEST_RT>
</TESTFILE>
<TESTFILE>
            <TESTFILE_ID>654317</TESTFILE_ID>
            <TESTVIN>DFG</TESTVIN>
            <TESTTYPE_ER>FD 91 MUX</TESTTYPE_ER>
        <TEST_RT>
                <TEST44_LONG_CS>B001_001_001</TEST44_LONG_CS>
        </TEST_RT>
</TESTFILE>
<TESTFILE>
            <TESTFILE_ID>654318</TESTFILE_ID>
            <TESTVIN>DFGD</TESTVIN>
            <TESTTYPE_ER>FD 91 MUX</TESTTYPE_ER>
        <TEST_RT>
                <TEST43_LONG_CS>B001_001_001</TEST41_LONG_CS>
        </TEST_RT>
        <TEST_RT>
                <TEST42_LONG_CS>B001_001_001</TEST41_LONG_CS>
        </TEST_RT>
</TESTFILE>
```

I tried reading the above file in JAVA and store each xml objects ( begins with `<TESTFILE>` and ends with `</TESTFILE>` ) as separate objects in  `List<String>`.
I tried with the following code:

```
public static List<String> readMessagesTest() throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<String> messageList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String content = "";
         try {
                content = new Scanner(new File("d:\\public\\testfile.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
              }catch(Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
         messageList.add(content);
        return messageList;
    }
```

The above code reads the entire xml text in the file and then I need to split the string and manually add it into the list.. 
Can anyone please suggest me an easy solution rather than doing this way ?

Comment: Can you please explain what are you doing to split the XML manually?

Comment: it would be far easier to create a jAXB object , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152046/unmarshalling-xml-using-jaxb (this also depends what you are trying to accomplish, keep in mind there are differences between sax and dom parsers)

Comment: @sathya_dev, I was about to split the whole string w.r.t the text " </TESTFILE>" , which is the end tag of a one complete xml  and store them  into list

Comment: @KennethClark thanks for your suggestion. I dont wish to use any libraries for this operation unless it is really necessary and here, I'm not trying to parse an xml file but just to read text file containing multiple similar xml and store each xml into db

Comment: Yes. Got it. If you got this method working . then go with it. It's good approach.(If you just use this to store the xml). I would suggest you to go with JAXB as @KennethClark mentioned,only if you're going to access the attributes or elements of the xml and further processing in other java classes.